# How make two repository for singe git working source

Tags: git, github

I newbie to using git, correct me if I am wrong,

### Case : 1

I want to work in single copy but when update (`git push filename origin branchname`), it needs to update in two repositories.

#### For example:

I have single working copy which cloned from Main Repo (A).
Now I want to test the working copy, so I need to update the file to Testing Repo (B) (which needs to be Repo- so that other will get clone) after testing I need to move it again to the Main Repo (A) by doing `git pull` from Repo(B) to my working copy (local) and `git push` to Repo(A)

### Case : 2

I pulled a file (`somefile.txt`-which is modified in repo) from Repo(A) and I also changed the same file (`somefile.txt`) in my local, When I git pull, that time it'll show error like "aborting due to changes in file , First commit your changes"

For that basically, I do first checkout the file and add my changes to the file and I add  commited it.

But what I want is "How to merge the same file in single command" and do this ll messed up the code ?

Thanks,
Jak.

Answer (score 2):

If remote repositories "`repoA`" and "`repoB`" represent the same set of files (with slightly different content for testing purposes), then I would argue you don't need two repos.

You can more easily update a file in two branches (one for `dev`, one for `test`), and push your repo to a unique remote repo (than trying to manage two push to two different repositories).

Comment: He is describing the Oxford Dictionary definition of branches :)